# cURL doesn´t send content type properly

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I´m trying to establish a connection to the Klarna playground server. For this case I need to create a HPP Session with the session_id from a customer. I already get the session_id with cURL, but when I try to send another cURL request, the content type is NULL.

I tried to create a function to set the cURL options properly, which works fine to create a KP session to receive the session_id from Klarna, but not for the HPP Session.

This code is to set the options for the cURL session, since just the URL and the data is changing, I provide them as a parameter.

```php
private function executeCurl( $url, $data ) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->setHeader()); // set header for request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); // set authorization
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username() . ":" . $this->password()); // set authorization
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set URL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // set data for request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $curl = curl_exec($ch);

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        var_dump($info);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $curl;
}
```

In this function the KP session_id is properly created and calls the function hostpayment.

```php
    public function start() {
        $data = $this->createJson();
        $curl = $this->executeCurl("https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions", $data);

        $data = json_decode($curl,true);

        $session_id = $data["session_id"];

        $this->hostpayment($session_id);
    }
```

In this function the HPP session should be created.

```php
    public function hostpayment($session_id) {
       $url = "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions/" . $session_id;

       $data = $this->createSessionJson($session_id);

       $curl = $this->executeCurl($url, $data);
       $data = json_decode($curl,true);

    }
```

I would expect, that the cURL output in both cases are the same, except for the URL and the data.

curl_getinfo outputed the following for the KP Session:

```
{ ["url"]=> string(54) "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions" ["content_type"]=> string(16) "application/json" ["http_code"]=> int(200) ["header_size"]=> int(290) ["request_size"]=> int(271)}
```

The HPP request outputs the following:

```
{ ["url"]=> string(91) "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions/53ac5196-ced3-7573-96c7-332a7b8ab0ae" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(204) ["header_size"]=> int(212) ["request_size"]=> int(307)}
```

You can see that the content type in the second request is null and the HTTP code is 204, so the request is successful, but the header isn´t set properly.

Comment: Isn't [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) an option?

Comment: I tried now, still no content typ is set, bux thanks for your help

Comment: how did u try to use Guzzle? Can u add what u did to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was trying to find out the problem, I was realising after hours of debugging, that Klarna uses very similar URLs, so instead of https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions/ I had to use https://api.playground.klarna.com/hpp/v1/sessions/ to receive the right data.